# React Native Expo babel.config.js only supported when running Babel asynchronously

Tags: react-native

I just add the boilerplate to a fresh expo app when I was hit with the following error:

```
navigation\StackNavigator.js: You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously.

ABI49_0_0RCTFatal
ABI49_0_0RCTConvertArrayValue
E389E46D-7BDA-33A1-9CF3-D8E5CC909C38
E389E46D-7BDA-33A1-9CF3-D8E5CC909C38
E389E46D-7BDA-33A1-9CF3-D8E5CC909C38
E389E46D-7BDA-33A1-9CF3-D8E5CC909C38
48524CDA-8D0D-3EAC-A286-69AE36B87031
48524CDA-8D0D-3EAC-A286-69AE36B87031
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
7CA2102B-17DC-3183-B7C0-6FC645514C0E
UIApplicationMain
main
D64B17E5-D3AD-3FEA-A25A-579091848AB9
```

I didn't touch the babel.config.js file since it was provided to me via npx create-expo-app but here's how it looks:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "expo": "~49.0.7",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And my file structure if it helps:

```
.expo
api
assets
components
navigation
node_modules
screens
.gitignore
App.js
babel.config.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

I'm completely new to React Native and following a tutorial so bear with me please, the following is my StackNavigator.js file:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "../screens/RegisterScreen";

const StackNavigator = () => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default StackNavigator;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```